# "Missing required property for hive.script" in azkaban

Tags: hadoop, hive, azkaban

This is my .job file

```
type=hive  
user.to.proxy=azkaban  
azk.hive.action=execute.query  
hive.query.01=SELECT * FROM TEST;
```

The job fails with this error:

```
Caused by: azkaban.utils.UndefinedPropertyException: Missing required property 'hive.script'
        at azkaban.utils.Props.getString(Props.java:483)
        at azkaban.jobtype.HadoopHiveJob.getScript(HadoopHiveJob.java:269)
        at azkaban.jobtype.HadoopHiveJob.getMainArguments(HadoopHiveJob.java:225)
        at azkaban.jobExecutor.JavaProcessJob.createCommandLine(JavaProcessJob.java:60)
        at azkaban.jobExecutor.JavaProcessJob.getCommandList(JavaProcessJob.java:49)
        at azkaban.jobExecutor.ProcessJob.run(ProcessJob.java:56)
```

I am using Azkaban 2.5 and cdh5

Answer (score 0):

Per latest document (http://azkaban.github.io/azkaban/docs/2.5/#hive-type). "The configurations have changed from the old Hive job type.". The .job file now expects hive.script instead of hive.query

Did you try moving the hive queries into a different file (say xyz.hive) and set path of that file in hive.script?